# how to pass parameter in init method of UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, swift4, init

Let me know if i have made any mistake don't downcast the question.

here is the problem i am trying to play a video and following is code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

// custom UIView to display frame for avplayer

class VideoPlayerView: UIView {

    let urlString String?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .blackColor()

        //static url for video

        urlString = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gameofchats-762ca.appspot.com/o/message_movies%2F12323439-9729-4941-BA07-2BAE970967C7.mov?alt=media&token=3e37a093-3bc8-410f-84d3-38332af9c726"
        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)

            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            playerLayer.frame = self.frame

            player.play()
        }

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

// view controller to launch video player

```
class VideoPlayerController: UIViewController {

    var message: Messages?{
        didSet{

        }
    }


    let overlayView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        return view
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .black

                let height = view.frame.width * 9 / 16
        let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: height)

        let videoPlayerView = VideoContainerView(frame: videoPlayerFrame)
        view.addSubview(videoPlayerView)

        videoPlayerView.center = view.center

    }
```

in the init method of VideoPlayerView i have used static url of video for urlString property which is playing fine. i want to set urlString property from my videoPlayerController class how i can do that ? because when i initialize

```
let view = VideoPlayerView(frame:frame) // this code will call init method before i can set the urlString property.
```

anyone have idea how to do that. please help. thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Just make other initializer with needed parameters and call it.

```
convenience init(frame: CGRect, urlString: String) {
    self.init(frame: frame)
    //make here what you want
}
```